# A View.environmentObject(_:) for may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swiftui

I just updated to Xcode 11.4 and it's broken my code. I am storing some user settings in an ObservableObject as follows:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {  
    @Published var cardOrder = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Card Order")  
    @Published var cardTheme = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Card Theme")  
    @Published var translation = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Translation")  
    @Published var overdueFirst = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Overdue First")  
    @Published var randomNum = 0  
}
```

This is my main menu, the settings environment object is successfully passed down to the Settings view where I'm able to save and retrieve user selections.

```
struct ContentView: View {  
  @State var settings = UserSettings()  

  var body: some View {  
    SubView().environmentObject(settings)  
  }  
}  

struct SubView: View {  

  @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings  

  var body: some View {  
    List {  
      NavigationLink (destination: Flashcard()){  
        HStack {  
          Image(systemName: "rectangle.on.rectangle.angled")  
          Text(verbatim: "Study")      
        }  
      }  

      NavigationLink (destination: Settings()) {  
        HStack {  
          Image(systemName: "gear")  
          Text(verbatim: "Settings")  
        }  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

But in my flashcard view, I am getting an error: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type UserSettings found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for UserSettings may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0

The error  is on line 13 where I initiate Frontside. In the original code, I just called the Frontside subview, but I thought to solve the error I had to add .environmentObject(settings), but even after adding it my app compiles but crashes as soon I go to the Flashcard view.

```
struct Flashcard: View {  
  @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings  

  @State var colour = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Card Theme") * 6  
  @State private var showResults: Bool = false  
  @State private var fullRotation: Bool = false  
  @State private var showNextCard: Bool = false  


  var body: some View {  
    let zstack = ZStack {  

      Frontside(id: $settings.randomNum, sheet: $showingSheet, rotate: $fullRotation, invis: $showNextCard, col: $colour).environmentObject(self.settings)  
      //   


      Backside(id: $settings.randomNum, sheet: $showingSheet, bookmark: $bookmarked, results: $showResults, rotate: $fullRotation, invis: $showNextCard, col: $colour, trans: $translation).environmentObject(self.settings)  
    //  

    }  
  }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? This code compiled and ran fine in the previous Xcode.

Comment: Exact same problem here. App was working fix before upgrading to 13.4 :/
It is working fine on the simulator, though. It only crashes on the device. For you as well?

Comment: No, mine crashes on the simulator too. The app loads fine but when I go to this specific view it is crashing. But I can't figure out what is wrong since I have other subviews using that environment object and they are not crashing.

Comment: For me, this happens only when my macOS-compatible iOS app runs on macOS. I don't get a crash on iOS, iPadOS, or tvOS. Weird. Adding the extra call to set the environment fixes it, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should pass `settings` object to `FlashCard` and `Settings` as well.
try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {  
  @State var settings = UserSettings()  

  var body: some View {  
    SubView().environmentObject(settings)  
  }  
}  

struct SubView: View {  

  @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings  

  var body: some View {  
    List {  
      NavigationLink (destination: Flashcard().environmentObject(settings)){  
        HStack {  
          Image(systemName: "rectangle.on.rectangle.angled")  
          Text(verbatim: "Study")      
        }  
      }  

      NavigationLink (destination: Settings().environmentObject(settings)) {  
        HStack {  
          Image(systemName: "gear")  
          Text(verbatim: "Settings")  
        }  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Why is this necessary, though? Shouldn't an environmentObject passed to an ancestor view (i.e. "SubView") automatically be accessible by descendant views (i.e. Flashcard and Settings)? What benefit does this approach give us over just passing directly as a property of the Flashcard/Settings views?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running iOS 14.3 in the simulator and in my case the error was about my environmentObject `NavigationController`. It was resolved by modifying `ContentView()` with `.environmentObject(NavigationController())` in the `SceneDelegate` and, if you want the preview to work, also in `ContentView_Previews`.

Answer (score 1):

An `@EnvironmentObject` has to be filled with an `@StateObject`, an `@ObservedObject` or an `ObservableObject` directly NOT an `@State`

```
struct ContentView: View {  
    //@ObservedObject
    @StateObject var settings = UserSettings()  

    var body: some View {  
        SubView().environmentObject(settings)  
    }  
}
```

Note: `UserSettings` has to be an `ObservableObject`

[Apple documentation on managing model data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

```
struct BookReader: App {
    @StateObject var library = Library()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LibraryView()
                .environmentObject(library)
        }
    }
}

struct LibraryView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var library: Library

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

@main

// there is a file with the name of your "projectApp" (JuegosSwiftUIApp in my case)

struct JuegosSwiftUIApp: App { 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            DatosIniciales() // any view
                .environmentObject(Datos()) // this solved it (Datos() is class type Observableobject) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.